# .Where clause on DateTime.Month

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, dynamics-crm-2011

Here is the situation:

I'm working on a basic search for a somewhat big entity. Right now, the amount of results is manageable but I expect a very large amount of data after a year or two of use, so performance is important here.

The object I'm browsing has a DateTime value and I need to be able to output all objects with the same month, regardless of the year. There are multiple search fields that can be combined, but the other fields do not cause a problem here.

I tried this :

```
if(model.SelectedMonth != null)
{
    contribs = contribs.Where(x => x.Date.Value.Month == model.SelectedMonth);
}

model.Contribs = contribs
    .Skip(NBRESULTSPERPAGE*(model.CurrentPage - 1))
    .Take(NBRESULTSPERPAGE)
    .ToList();
```

So far all I get is "Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method." I thought of just invoking ToList() but it doesn't seem to be very efficient, again the entity is quite big. I'm looking for a clean way to make this work.

Comment: LINQ to what? LINQ to Entities? LINQ to SQL? Some other provider?

Comment: I dont see a problem, can you post the inner exception you got

Comment: LINQ to XRM.Entities (Microsoft Dynamics 2011)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> The object I'm browsing has a DateTime value and I need to be able to output all objects with the same month, regardless of the year
>
> ...
>
> I expect a very large amount of data after a year or two of use, so performance is important here.

Right there, you have a problem.  I understand you are using [LINQ to CRM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681573.aspx), but this problem would actually come up regardless of what technology you're using.

The underlying problem is that date and time is stored in a single field.  The year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds, and fractional seconds are all packed into a single integer that represents the number of units since some time.  In the case of a `DateTime` in .NET, that's the number of *ticks* since 1/1/0001.  If the value is stored in a SQL `DateTime2` field, it's the same thing.  Other data types have different start dates (epochs) and different precisions.  But in all cases, there's just a single number internally.

If you're searching for a value that is in a month of a *particular* year, then you could get decent performance from a range query.  For example, give all values >= 2014-01-01 and < 2014-02-01.  Those two points can be mapped back to their numeric representation in the database.  If the field has an index, then a range query can use that index.

But if the value you're looking for is just a *month*, then any query you provide will require the database to extract that month from each and every value in the table.  This is also known as a "table scan", and no amount of indexing will help.

A query that can effectively use an index is known as a [*sargable*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) query.  However, the query you are attempting is non-sargable because it has to evaluate every value in the table.

I don't know how much control over the object and its storage you have in CRM, but I will tell you what I usually recommend for people querying a SQL Server directly:

- Store the month in a separate column as a single integer.  Sometimes this can be a *computed* column based on the original datetime, such that you never have to enter it directly.
- Create an index that includes this column.
- Use this column when querying by month, so that the query is sargable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess and really should be a comment, but it's too much code to format well in a comment.  If it's not helpful I'll delete the answer.

Try moving `model.SelectedMonth` to a variable rather than putting it in the `Where` clause

```
var selectedMonth = model.SelectedMonth;
if(selectedMonth != null)
{
    contribs = contribs.Where(x => x.Date.Value.Month == selectedMonth);
}
```

you might do the same for `CurrentPage` as well:

```
int currentPage = model.CurrentPage;

model.Contribs = contribs
    .Skip(NBRESULTSPERPAGE*(currentPage - 1))
    .Take(NBRESULTSPERPAGE)
    .ToList();
```

Many query providers work better with variables than properties of non-related objects.

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of `model.SelectedMonth`?

According to your code logic it is nullable, and it appears that it might be a struct, so does this work?

```
if (model.SelectedMonth.HasValue)
{
    contribs = contribs.Where(x => x.Date.Value.Month == model.SelectedMonth.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to create a Month OptionSet Attribute on your contrib Entity, which is populated via a plugin on the create/update of the entity for the Date Attribute.  Then you could search by a particular month, and rather than searching a Date field, it's searching an int field.  This would also make it easy to search for a particular month in the advanced find.

The Linq to CRM Provider isn't a full fledged version of Linq.  It generally doesn't support any sort of operation on the attribute in your where statement, since it has to be converted to whatever QueryExpressions support.